# Codeigniter 3 form not posting

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth, codeigniter-3

***UPdate, it would appear none of the forms seem to post correctly. They all load whatever URL is specified in action put no POST data is available.**

My app is running fine on Lamp locally. Once uploaded to my live server the login form will not function. I am using CI3 and the Ion Auth library.

I have tried 
`var_dump($_POST)`

which always outputs the following:

```
array(0) {
```

}

So it would seem that the form is not posting. My Form:

```
<?php echo form_open("auth/login");?>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <?php echo form_input($identity);?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <?php echo form_input($password);?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-theme-xs mr-8">Login</button>
                                <?php echo form_checkbox('remember', '1', FALSE, 'id="remember"');?>
                                <a href="<?= site_url('auth/forgot_password') ?>" class="text-theme-xs pull-right a-black">Forgot your password ?</a>
                            </form>
```

The post to URL is the same as the one the form is displayed on, and as I say it works fine on lamp. Firebug shows errors about password field and unsecure site but I assumed this wouldnt prevent the form from posting?

I have replaced the redirects with var_dump but nothing happens, the issue is that there is no _POST data being sent.

Controller:

```
function login()
{
    $this->data['title'] = "Login";

    //validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('identity', 'Identity', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    {
        //check to see if the user is logging in
        //check for "remember me"
        $remember = (bool) $this->input->post('remember');

        if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember))
        {
            //if the login is successful
            //redirect them back to the home page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
            redirect('/', 'refresh');
        }
        else
        {
            //if the login was un-successful
            //redirect them back to the login page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
            redirect('auth/login', 'refresh'); //use redirects instead of loading views for compatibility with MY_Controller libraries
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //the user is not logging in so display the login page
        //set the flash data error message if there is one
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');

        $this->data['identity'] = array('name' => 'identity',
            'id' => 'identity',
            'type' => 'text',
                            'class' => 'form-control',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('identity'),
                            'placeholder' => 'Username',
        );
        $this->data['password'] = array('name' => 'password',
            'id' => 'password',
            'type' => 'password',
                            'class' => 'form-control',
                            'placeholder' => 'Password',
        );
                    $this->_render_page('templates/head', $this->data);
        $this->_render_page('templates/navbar', $this->data);
                    $this->_render_page('auth/login', $this->data);
                    $this->_render_page('templates/footer', $this->data);
    }
}
```

The html output from the abiove controller/view:

```
<form action="http://www.mydomain.uk/auth/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

  <p>
    <label for="identity">Email/Username:</label>    <input type="text" name="identity" value="" id="identity" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"  />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="remember">Remember Me:</label>    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" id="remember" />
  </p>


  <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"  />
</p>

</form>
```

Comment: Do you have the form `action` set correctly?

Comment: show us your controller code also in main post and in action use `<?php echo base_url('auth/login');?>` or with index.php `<?php echo base_url('index.php/auth/login');?>` make sure url helper autoloaded. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: I use form_open('auth/login') I will post controller above. It is standard Ion auth Controller.

Comment: I think you have your form inputs wrong

Comment: FWIW, I am using CI 3 with Ion Auth and having no trouble at all.  I also see nothing wrong with your posted code.  If you have it working locally, then you have to assume the issue is someplace on your server.  No matter what Controller function or URL, AFAIK, you should still have a POST array.

Comment: *"Firebug shows errors about password field and unsecure site but I assumed this wouldnt prevent the form from posting?"*  ~ There is no browser security requirement for simply posting a form.

Comment: I have to ask... have you also tried `var_dump($_POST)` on your local setup to verify that you're calling this in the right place?

Comment: Describe the exact observations of *"form will not function"* ~ Are you getting an error screen, does the page even reload, etc?  Ion Auth is very good about giving detailed error messages.  Do you have CSRF enabled in CI or Ion Auth.  I found that it's more reliable to use CI's built in CSRF protection, rather than what's built into Ion Auth.

Comment: The page does reload.  I tried var_dump ($_post) in the form validation so if it was true or false and neither worked. I put it as first line of the controller method and it spits out an empty array. The form  basically doesn't post it would seem

Comment: sparky what php version is your server running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this and I am extremely annoyed with myself as it was a simple fix due to a config error. aren't the most brain racking problems always like this?

Anyway for anyone else having the same issue check your site_url in config.

Mine was set to http://www.example.com however the server redirected to http://example.com therefore using site_url to post to got redirected to the non www domain losing the post data.

Now time to move on with what I should of spent my weekend doing.

Thank you for everyones attempts to help

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable apache2 mod_rewrite module